# Problema com join query PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Boas,

E o seguinte eu tenho uma `query` `JOIN` que me faz a consulta a 3 tabelas, que me busca no banco todas as notificações existentes dos seguidores do utilizador actualmente logado. O problema e que agora estava a tentar buscar as informações do utilizador que enviou a notificação, para mostrar na notificação mas a query deixa de me retornar dados. Pelo que pode ver ele retorna 500 error server.

**Código**

```
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate'); 
//Alteramos o cabeçalho para que o retorno seja do tipo JSON 
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

session_start();

require_once("../funcoes/funcoes.php");

$user_actual = $_REQUEST['user_logado'];


$result_notificacoes = $conexao->prepare("SELECT * FROM notificacoes as noti 
                                    LEFT JOIN notificacoes_visualizacao as noti_vi ON noti_vi.id_notificacao = noti.id 
                                    INNER JOIN users_social as user ON user.id = noti.user_id
                                    WHERE noti.user_id IN (SELECT seg.followed FROM seguidores as seg WHERE seg.follower = :user_actual) 
                                    AND noti_vi.id_usuario_que_visualizou is NULL 
                                    OR noti.user_destino_notificacao = :user_atual2");                                  

$result_notificacoes->bindValue(':user_actual', $user_actual, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$result_notificacoes->bindValue(':user_atual2', $user_actual, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$result_notificacoes->execute();

$return = array();

$notificacoes = $result_notificacoes->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach ($notificacoes as $row_notificacoes) {

    $sql = $conexao->prepare("INSERT INTO notificacoes_visualizacao (id_notificacao, id_usuario_que_visualizou) VALUES (:id_notificacao, :id_usuario_que_visualizou)");
    $sql->bindValue(':id_notificacao', $row_notificacoes['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $sql->bindValue(':id_usuario_que_visualizou', $user_actual, PDO::PARAM_INT); 
    $sql->execute();

$return[] = '
    <table border="0" class="barra_notificacoes" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td valign="top" width="10%">
                <div style="margin-left: 4px; margin-top: 5px;"><img width="50" height="50" src="images/avatar6.jpg"></div>
            </td>
            <td valign="top" width="50%">
                <div style="margin-left: 5px; margin-top: 2px;"><a href="users/<?= $row_user_anex->slug; ?>">César Sousa</a></div>
                <div style="margin-left: 5px;" class="comentario_user">Comentou a tua opinião!</div>
                <div style="margin-left: 5px;" class="tempo_do_post">1 segundo atrás</div> 
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    ';                  
}
echo json_encode($return);
```

O problema esta quando adiciono esta linha, a query deixa de funcionar

```
 INNER JOIN users_social as user ON user.id = noti.user_id
```

**Error log**

```
 sabeonde/public_html/ajax/mostra_notificacoes.php:22
 Stack trace:
 #0 /home/sabeonde/public_html/ajax/mostra_notificacoes.php(22): PDOStatement->execute()
 #1 {main}
 thrown in /home/sabeonde/public_html/ajax/mostra_notificacoes.php on line 22
```

**Erro do try**

```
 constraint fails (`sabeonde_sabeonde`.`notificacoes_visualizacao`, CONSTRAINT     `fk_notificacao_visualizacao_notificacao` FOREIGN KEY (`id_notificacao`) REFERENCES  `notificacoes` (`id`))' in /home/sabeonde/public_html/ajax/mostra_notificacoes.php:41
 Stack trace:
 #0 /home/sabeonde/public_html/ajax/mostra_notificacoes.php(41): PDOStatement->execute()
 #1 {main}
```

Comment: O que quer dizer "deixa de funcionar"? Não retorna resultados? Retorna resultados errados? O PHP da erro? Qual a estrutura das tabelas envolvidas? Descreva o que deseja obeter com a query.

Comment: Eu editei a pergunta e expliquei melhor e coloquei todo o código

Comment: Obrigado pelos detalhes. No caso do erro 500, verifique o log de erros do PHP. O caminho deste arquivo varia de distro para distro, e de hospedagem para hospedagem. O caminho padrão no CentOS, por exemplo, é `/var/log/httpd/error_log`. Adicione o trecho do log relevante à pergunta, por favor.

Comment: tive verifica e acusa o seguinte erro vou colocar acima no post

Comment: Coloque o comando `$result_notificacoes->execute();` dentro de um block `try-catch` para ver qual a mensagem associada com a exceção gerada. Veja esta página para mais detalhes de como fazer isso: http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdoexception.php Adicione a mensagem à pergunta, caso não consiga entendê-la.

Comment: Coloquei o errro na mensagem nao percebo o que segnifica

Comment: Não sou especialista em MySQL. Aparentemente, alguma restrição de integridade de chave estrangeira que o MySQL deveria ter verificado anteriormente, esta falhando. Isso significa que seu banco de dados esta inconsistente. Você terá que analisar aonde esta falhando a integridade com o uso de uma ferramento como o MySQL Workbench. A mensagem de erro te indica a tabela e qual restrição esta com problemas, então não deve ser uma tarefa muito difícil. Feito isso, o problema deve se resolver, ou pelo menos o erro 500 deve deixar de acontecer.

Comment: mas eu se tirar o inner join a tabela users_social ele já da bem

Comment: Sim porque neste caso o MySQL não passa pela falha de integridade, e portanto não gera o erro. Mas você também não obtém o resultado esperado. Restrições de integridade de modo geral foram criadas para serem respeitadas. MySQL é famoso por ter problemas com isso. Ou você corrige as falhas através de modificações no seu código, ou você troca de SGBD, ou você convive com erros bizarros que vão afetar a estabilidade da sua aplicação.

Comment: Então vamos a ver se percebi isto e problema do MySQL ?

Comment: Sim e não. O problema (falha de integridade) foi causado por uma falha do MySQL ou por um erro de configuração seu, mas isso foi antes, no momento da inserção dos dados. Agora, este problema esta aparecendo no momento que o MySQL vai realizar os produtos do JOIN. Qual engine de armazenamento você esta utilizando (MyISAM, INNO,...)? A escolha dela influencia o suporte a restrições de integridade do MySQL.

Comment: Para as tabelas que usam chave estrangeira estou a usar INNO

Comment: Não sei qual o comportamento ao se misturar INNO com MyISAM, sendo que as tabelas referenciadas estão no MyISAM e as que referenciam estão no INNO. Provavelmente é este o problema. Utilize INNO em todas, ou verifique na documentação (procurei e não encontrei) algo que te de respaldo sobre misturar as duas e ainda manter integridade.

Comment: Estou a fazer download do MySQL Workbench para ver o que esta a falhar

Comment: Na tua opiniao qual seria a solução a nivel de base dados para um projecto que irá ter um grande volume de users e conteudos

Comment: Nos sistemas que desenvolvo, volume de dados e integridade é fundamental, por isso sempre utilizo PostgreSQL ou Oracle, dependendo do cliente. MySQL já tive muitos problemas, até que mudamos todos os sistemas da empresa para Postgre (Oracle é opção do cliente devido ao custo), e desde a mudança, nossos problemas foram absolutamente zero. Nunca mais tivemos um único problema e em termos de desempenho não houveram alterações. Além disso, Postgre tem a vantagem de seguir padrões (ao contrário da bagunça que o MySQL), e conversa super bem com Oracle. Então minha opinião é Postgre.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21946/discussion-between-vinicius-gobbo-a-de-oliveira-and-cesar-sousa).